# Blank space left about itemized list. How to remove this vertical space?

Tags: lists, itemize, white-space, vspace

I am trying to remove vertical space inserted when I start a itemized list inside a table using the `\tabular` command:

```
\begin{tabular}{@{} p{0.18\textwidth}|p{0.82\textwidth}}
\raggedright \textbf{Lists drive me crazy} \newline \footnotesize{Jan 2018-Present} 
& \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=3mm, noitemsep, topsep=0pt]
\item please
\item work
\end{itemize}
\end{tabular}
```

It comes out like this:
[image]

As you can see, whining about it got me nowhere

If anyone can tell me the proper way to eliminate the vertical spacing for this one local example and just have it flush with the top so it lines up perfectly with the text in the left-hand column, that would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code (`\compress` is borrowed from another answer – I don't remember which):

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{} p{0.18\textwidth}| >{\compress\arraybackslash}p{0.82\textwidth}}
\raggedright \textbf{Lists drive me crazy} \newline \footnotesize{Jan 2018-Present}
& \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=3mm, nosep, after = \vskip-\baselineskip]
\item please
\item work
\item please
\item work
\end{itemize}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It didn't work I'm afraid. I feel it's a little excessive as a work around too! Thank you for the help though.

Comment: I was hoping that there would have been a more elegant solution to something I thought would have been simpler

Comment: Simpler than adding `>{\compress}`?

Comment: Hi Bernard, just had a play and managed to get it working! This is new to me so it can take a while. Sometimes the solution is so simple like adding nosep but this one was tricky. 
I see what you mean; it isn't as bad as it seems.
Could you explain each added pieces of code?

1) the use of >

2) the use of \compress

3) the use of \arraybackslash

4) nosep, after = \vskip-\baselineskip]

5) the added parts in the preamble like makeatletter and minipagetrue

Comment: 1) `>{some commànd(s)}` is defined by the array package: the commands are executed at the very beginning of each cell in corresponding column. 2) So \compress is executed. It is there to make LaTeX believe we're at the beginning of a minipage, so there s no \newline added at the beginning of a list. 3) For paragraph type columns,`\arraybackslash`  is to avoid any confusion between the end-of_line marker in the paragraph cell and the end-of-row marker in tabular.

Comment: 4) `nosep` removes the vertical skips added at the  beginning of a list and between items. Besides, at the end of the list, a \newline is added to the cell. `after=\vskip-\baselineskip` neutralises that unwanted vertical spacing. 5) \makeatletter ... \makeatother is used because we need a command (`\@minipagetrue) which contains the `@` character, which shouldn't be used in normal commands (it is used in .sty and .cls files, for technical reasons).