# Remove vertical indentation above itemize list

Tags: vertical-alignment, indentation, itemize, vertical, vertical-spacing

When I make a bullet point list in a table, the first bullet point does not line up with the text in the adjacent cell. How do I remove this indent so the line up horizontally?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother

\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.2in,%
            left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,%
            footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem} % for formatting itemized lists
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{tabularx} % allows for tables to be created by coloumn spacing instead of line spacing as in tabular
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}%imports the a colour pallet for things like lines
\usepackage{colortbl} %allows colour fomratting for table lines

\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm} % sets the column divider space in between columns
\date{} % Removes the date
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hfuzz=5pt % The \hfuzz setting specifies the maximum amount of box-overflow before a warning message will be issued.
\pagenumbering{gobble}%gets rid of page numbers
\title{\vspace{-1cm}\Huge Curriculum Vitae}
\author{\Large\textbf{name}\\email\\number}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{0.18\linewidth}!{\color{RawSienna}\vrule width 0.3mm}X@{}}
\raggedright \textbf{insert profession here} \newline \footnotesize{dates} 
& \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=5mm, itemsep=1mm, after = \vskip-\baselineskip]
\item BLA
\item BLA 2
\item BLA 3
\end{itemize}\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: **(1)** https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/544414 seems related. **(2)** Any reason why none of your six questions has an accepted answer?

Answer (score 2):

The following is a faux implementation of an `itemize` within your `tabular`, called `tabularitemize`. It redefines `\item` to insert a tabular newline (`\\`) followed by a `\textbullet` and a column skip `&` - the faux list has a first column for the `\textbullet` and a second `p`aragraph column for the item content.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx} % allows for tables to be created by coloumn spacing instead of line spacing as in tabular
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} % imports the a colour pallet for things like lines
\usepackage{colortbl} % allows colour formatting for table lines

\usepackage{environ}
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{tabularitemize}{%
  \global\let\olditem\item
  \def\item{\gdef\item{\\ \textbullet&}\textbullet&}%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}wr{1em}@{\hspace{\tabcolsep}}p{\dimexpr\linewidth-1em-\tabcolsep}@{}}
    \BODY
  \end{tabular}
  \global\let\item\olditem
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{0.18\linewidth}!{\color{RawSienna}\vrule width 0.3mm}X@{}}
  \raggedright \textbf{insert profession here} \newline \footnotesize{dates} 
  & \begin{tabularitemize}
    \item Blah 1 The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. 
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. 
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
    \item Blah 2 The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. 
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
    \item Blah 3
  \end{tabularitemize}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

The `\textbullet` column is `1em` in width (and `r`ight-aligned) with a `\tabcolsep` between the bullet and the item content.

Answer (score 2):

Just insert `compress` before `X` column:

```
begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{0.18\linewidth}!{\color{RawSienna}\vrule width 0.3mm}
                             >{\compress}X@{}}
```

and result will become as follows:

[image]

Complee MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother

\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.2in,%
            margin=2cm,%
            footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem} % for formatting itemized lists
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{tabularx} % allows for tables to be created by coloumn spacing instead of line spacing as in tabular
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}%imports the a colour pallet for things like lines

\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm} % sets the column divider space in between columns
\date{} % Removes the date
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hfuzz=5pt % The \hfuzz setting specifies the maximum amount of box-overflow before a warning message will be issued.
\pagenumbering{gobble}%gets rid of page numbers
\title{\vspace{-1cm}\Huge Curriculum Vitae}
\author{\Large\textbf{name}\\email\\phone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{0.18\linewidth}!{\color{RawSienna}\vrule width 0.3mm}
                             >{\compress}X@{}}
\raggedright \textbf{insert profession here} \newline \footnotesize{dates}
& \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=5mm, itemsep=1mm, 
                  after = \vskip-\baselineskip]
\item BLA
\item BLA 2
\item BLA 3
\end{itemize}\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```